# Lenses with Sum Types (that have Product types)

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell      #-}

import Control.Lens

data Fruit = Fruit
  { _fruitColor :: String
  }

$(makeClassy ''Fruit)

data Fruits =
    Banana Int Fruit
  | Strawberry String Fruit

printer :: HasFruit s => s -> IO ()
printer f = putStrLn $ f ^. fruitColor

sample :: IO ()
sample = do
  printer $ Fruit "yellow"
  printer $ Banana 5 $ Fruit "yellow"
```

I have a core product type, Fruit. I want to have data types that all contain the core product type, Fruit, but want to be able to have them represented by a sum type, Fruits. Using the sum type, Fruits, I'd like to be able to access components of the core product type, Fruit. Namely, I'd like types like Banana and Strawberry to be an instance of HasFruit.

Is there a straightforward way to have Fruits instantiate HasFruit? Is there a better pattern to represent this - core product type in a sum type?

Comment: I don't know if the lens package can derive such an instance, but you can just write it yourself: `instance HasFruit Fruits where fruit k (Banana x f) = Banana x <$> k f ; fruit k (Strawberry x f) = Strawberry x <$> k f`. It should be noted that `Banana` and `Strawberry` are *not* types - and cannot be made instances of classes because they are not types. They are constructors which return a value of type `Fruit`.

Answer (score 1):

It would make more sense to do something like this:

```
data FruitType = Banana Int | Strawberry String

data Fruits = Fruits { _fruitsFruitType :: FruitType, _fruitsFruit :: Fruit }

makeFields ''Fruits

-- `Fruits` now instantiates `HasFruit`
```

You might also want to make prisms for `FruitType`. Prisms are essentially traversals into different parts of a sum type, except they can also be used to construct it.

```
makePrisms ''FruitType

-- double the int if the argument is a `Banana`

doubleBanana = fruitType._Banana *~ 2
```